# KVM guest os boot error

Tags: linux, permissions, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I'm trying to boot up a guest os to continue with my work but I have a problem with my virsh installation.
Here is the part of installation script:

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 -o preallocation=metadata ~/images/${vm_name}.qcow2 ${pool_size}G

# create dir for images
mkdir ~/images/

virt-install \
--connect qemu:///system \
--name $vm_name \
--ram 10240 \
--vcpus 4 \
--disk ~/images/${vm_name}.qcow2,size=$pool_size,bus=virtio,sparse=false,format=qcow2 \
--network network=default,model=virtio \
--location http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/dists/trusty-updates/main/installer-amd64/ \
--initrd-inject=$current_dir/preseed.cfg \
--extra-args="file=file:/preseed.cfg vga=788 quiet console=tty0 utf8 console=ttyS0,115200" \
--os-type=linux \
--virt-type kvm \
--video=vga \
--noreboot \
--cpu host \
--hvm

virsh start $vm_name
echo "----------Login to console----------"
virsh console $vm_name
```

WHen Im trying to run this script as a file like ./script.sh it produces an error:

```
Formatting '/home/{username}/images/test.qcow2', fmt=qcow2 size=53687091200 encryption=off cluster_size=65536 preallocation='metadata' lazy_refcounts=off refcount_bits=16
mkdir: cannot create directory '/home/flash/images/': File exists
ERROR    'DebianDistro' object has no attribute '_prefix'
error: failed to get domain 'test'
error: Domain not found: no domain with matching name 'test'

----------Login to console----------
error: failed to get domain 'test'
error: Domain not found: no domain with matching name 'test'
```

I have tried already reinstalling kvm qemu packages using this guide - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation
and everything completed successfully.
I am sure that script will work file as I was using it before on the other machine without any problems.

Another try:
Using that script below

```
virt-install --connect qemu:///system -n test -r 10240 \
--vcpus=4 \
--disk path=/data0/images/test.img,size=50,format=qcow2,bus=virtio,cache=none \
--cdrom /home/{username}/Downloads/kvm/ubuntu-14.iso \
--vnc \
--os-type=linux \
--accelerate \
--network network=default \
--hvm
```

Produces an error:

```
ERROR    internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: Could not access KVM kernel module: Permission denied
failed to initialize KVM: Permission denied
```

Also when I'm trying to list all os variants by virt-install --os-variant list it cannot recognize this command and trying to boot up a guest os instead of listing variants.

Can you please help me to find out what is the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

To fix this error:

```
ERROR    'DebianDistro' object has no attribute '_prefix'
```

Edit the file `/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/urlfetcher.py` and change this in line 1034:

```
if self._prefix:
```

to this:

```
if self._url_prefix:
```

Ubuntu 14.04.